# Print counter value minus 1

Tags: counters

I have defined a new counter that keeps increasing each time I call the macro that's using it. How can I print the counter value *minus* one? Something like `\value{\theCounter-1}` but formatted for text?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcounter{myCount}
\setcounter{myCount}{1}
\newcommand\newSec[1]{\par\underline{\textsc{newSec}~\themyCount}\hspace{0.5em}{\footnotesize(#1~number)}\stepcounter{myCount}\par}

\begin{document}
    \newSec{2}
    Some text

    \newSec{5}
    Here I refer to the counter used before it was incremented: \themyCount. Should print 2. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\setcounter{myCount}{0}` and move the set counter `\par\stepcounter{myCount}` before `underline`.

Comment: why aren't you using any of the latex machinery for section or list item  headings? this looks sort of like a heading but you can't `\label` it, you may get a page break between the heading and the text and everything else the section heading code takes care of isn't taken care of.

Comment: It was an emergency solution to using the `exam` class. Good thought about incrementing the counter first. Solves it!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 \the\numexpr\value{counter}-1\relax
```

should do what is asked in the question but you don't seem to need this, it is normal to advance the counter before using it, then its value in a section will be the value used in that sections heading, and you don't need to subtract.

Comment: Error: `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) ...print 2. \the\dimexpr\value{myCount}\relax` Why's that?

Comment: @Holene because you used what I wrote not what I meant to write (`numexpr` not `dimexpr` sorry)

Comment: If I only want the actual value without increasing it, it is okay to just remove the "-1"?

Comment: @JoelDuscha yes but `\thecounter` would be more normal in that case (that's the specified print form)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Any hints why this solution does not work in this context: **\tikzset{myset/.style={row #1 column 1/.style={execute at begin node=Week \space \the\numexpr\value{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}-1}}}**    . Folks: I don't think it make sense to ask this as another question so I'm posting as a comment but if I'm wrong please let me know.

Comment: Please don't ask questions  as comments on old answers, but does `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` expand to the name of a counter? I suspect it does not, in which case it  is unrelated to the code here. @SergioParreiras

Comment: Thanks for correcting my wrong assumptions about the site rules. I just replaced \pgfmatrixcurrentrow (counter name) with #1 and it solved my problem (no idea why...)